# Automating Node and Angular frontend/backend Integration, production preparation and deployment?

Tags: node.js, angularjs, socket.io, gruntjs, yeoman

I have been experimenting with Node.js for a while and have hacked together simple projects with [Express](http://expressjs.com/), [Hapi](http://spumko.github.io/) and [Restify](http://mcavage.me/node-restify/).  The frontends on these small projects were very small and limited, as I was primarily focused on the backend, so I never had the need to automate a lot of the details when deploying them to production servers.

I recently started getting into front end development and stumbled across some great automation tools; [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) (overall workflow), [Yo](https://github.com/yeoman/yo) (for scaffolding), [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/) (automation) and [Bower](http://bower.io/) (for dependencies).

I absolutely love the workflow of these tools and they have gotten me really excited about trying to learn front end development, structuring and workflow.  However, learning all of this has also raised questions on the proper way to automate other areas of workflow that integrate the front and back ends:

1) Should I be maintaining the frontend and backend in the same repository?  They are both written in JavaScript but it seems semi clunky.  I know this is a matter of preference but I would love to see some thoughts on current best practices.  Would it be best to have the public directory in my app be a sym link to another.

2) How do I wire my front end to my backend?  Specifically talking about socket.io calls.  I am not sure the best way to automate how to best set this variable.  In the backend I would use process.env, but I am unsure how to accomplish wiring them together based on test, production settings.  I do not want to hand change this everytime I deploy to server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) I like the idea of keeping them in the same repository. It makes your life so much easier as you go along. The one thing you will feel happy is once your server and web pages are being served from same web server, you dont need to deal with any of the CORS issues. Or you don't need to have a reverse proxy just to resolve CORS issue.

2) We use angular js with socket.io calls. Since you use yeoman, you can read a config file into the Gruntfile.js like this.   `grunt.file.readJSON('config.json').`   You can reuse your grunt scripts if you have a CI.

```
nodeServer : {
   prod : {
       port: 8080, //other params
   } 
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on how I would use this config file w/ grunt to inject the proper info into the HTML or JS?

Comment: In your js, you can use require to load the same config.json like `require('config.json'). That will give you your config object. You can find out the node environment using process.env.ENVIRONMENT. Make sure you are setting this ENVIRONMENT in your grunt file. So, once you get your json and you know the environment, you can use the port and other settings.

Comment: @Hortinstein: If your issue is resolved, can you please mark this as answered. It will help others. Else, let me know.